# Windows azure storage membership blob permissions

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-acs

An azure web role, that uses membership authentication, how can we give permissions to roles and users to specific blobs in a container or to container itself? For example admin role has full control over container and blobs, customers have read permissions over invoices documents in the container and so forth ...?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you  are going to be able to use roles directly.  Blob and container only understand key, public, and shared access signature.   You could give users the appropriate shared access signature(s) based on their roles(s).